# SerializationError Rebuilding Elastic Search Django App

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I was using Whoosh with Haystack and everything works fine, I want to change to ElasticSearch but when I run rebuild_index I get the following error. I am not sure why the error is happening, it appears to be complaining about my Models and the data, however if I switch back to Whoosh search/indexing all work fine.

```
Django==1.8.4
elasticsearch==2.3.0
django-haystack==2.4.1
```

> File
>   "C:\Users\user.virtualenvs\pguider\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\serializer.py",
>   line 50, in dumps
>       raise SerializationError(data, e) elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({u'django_id': u'1',
>   'created': '2016-02-13T22:19:28.037000+00:00', 'suppl ier_code':
>   u'BL32291', 'related_supplier_parts': [], u'django_ct':
>   u'products.supplierpart', 'supplier': u'Parts Town', 'text':
>   u'BL32291\n32291\nBlodgett\n\nParts Town\n\n\n', 'part_code':
>   u'32291', u'id': u'products.supplierpart.1'}, Type Error("Unable to
>   serialize [] (type: )",))

Here are my models:

```
from django.db import models


class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name


class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.code, self.name)


class SupplierPart(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part)

    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    supplier_code = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)
    sale_price = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)

    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', null=True)
    url = models.URLField()

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.supplier_code

    @property
    def related_supplier_parts(self):
        return self.part.supplierpart_set.all().exclude(pk=self.pk)
```

Comment: Looks like elasticsearch can't serialize the list field which is `related_supplier_parts`. Can you tell what's that filed?

Comment: @BartoszDabrowski  looks like it is complaining about my foreign key field right? I have updated my question to include the models

Answer (score 1):

The problem lays in your property `related_supplier_parts`. Elastic search can't serialize it. This property returns queryset.

```
>>> parts = Part.objects.all()
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'related_supplier_parts': parts})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: [] is not JSON serializable
```

How to solve it?

The best for any project is to not complicate your models with properties. Although we know they are widely used and easy to write. I have never used any property in my Django career. In my current project I have 153 models and not a single property. In 99% cases you don't need them because simple method `get_related_supplier_parts` should do same job.

```
class SupplierPart(models.Model):
    [...]

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.supplier_code

    def get_related_supplier_parts(self):
        return self.part.supplierpart_set.all().exclude(pk=self.pk)
```

One more downside of @property is whenever you try to serialize object additional queries will be executed and think about serializing millions of them. You don't need to worry about it with method.

If you reject this for some reason you will need to find a way to convert this query to list. Probably in your index class defining new field:

```
class MyIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    [...]
    related_supplier_parts = indexes.MultiValueField()

    def prepare_related_supplier_parts(self, obj):
        return [part.id for part in obj.related_supplier_parts]
```

Comment: Hello @Bartosz Thank You for the full explanation. I was actually able to handle this by changing my search_index.py file from                          return obj.related_supplier_parts        To the following:
       return list(str(part) for part in obj.related_supplier_parts)              Thanks for the help!