# elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError + Django

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

Am embedding elastic search in my application, though when I run it I get this error :

```
 raise TypeError("Unable to serialize %r (type: %s)" % (data, type(data)))
TypeError: Unable to serialize <QuerySet [<AccountTypes: MENTOR>]> (type: <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>)


elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({'owner': {'id': 2, 'email': 'huxy@gmail.com', 'username': 'huxy', 'auth_provider': 'email', 'account_types': <QuerySet [<AccountTypes: MENTOR>]>, 'profile': <Profile: None Idris>, 'uuid': UUID('d4a5cae3-44ad-49c0-bf89-cc5f4d993667'), 'status': 'PENDING'}, 'tags': [], 'comments': [], 'grade_level': {}, 'title': 'Math is fun', 'body': 'Math is nice, now I like it so much, this is awesom', 'image': '', 'status': 'DRAFT'}, TypeError("Unable to serialize <QuerySet [<AccountTypes: MENTOR>]> (type: <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>)"))
```

What could be the one thing that am missing, below is my code snippets.

This is my model for user :

```
class User(MainProcess, django_models.AbstractBaseUser, TimeStampedModel,
           django_models.PermissionsMixin):
    """
    User model for the user creation
    """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, max_length=500,
                            default=uuid.uuid4,
                            editable=False,
                            db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), db_index=True, unique=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(_('Is verified'), default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('Is staff'), default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Is Active'), default=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('Username'), max_length=255,
                                blank=True, null=True)
    account_types = models.ManyToManyField(AccountTypes,
                                           related_name='account_types')
    auth_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False,
        null=False, default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=UserProcess.states,
        default=PENDING, max_length=100, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

Then this is a Post model :

```
class Post(MainProcess, TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    """Post model."""
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100, blank=False,
                             null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), upload_to='blog_images', null=True,
                              max_length=900)
    body = models.TextField(_('Body'), blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(_('Description'), max_length=400,
                                   blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default=uuid.uuid4(), unique=True, max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookmarks = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='bookmarks',
                                       default=None, blank=True)
    address_views = models.ManyToManyField(CustomIPAddress,
                                           related_name='address_views',
                                           default=None, blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', default=None,
                                   blank=True,
                                   )
```

Then my documents.py file :

```
@registry.register_document
class UserDocument(Document):

    """User Document."""

    account_types = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'uuid': fields.TextField(),
        'name': fields.TextField(),
    })

    class Index:
        name = 'users'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }


    class Django:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'email',
            'username',
            'status',
            'auth_provider',
        ]


@registry.register_document
class TagDocument(Document):

    """Tag Document"""

    class Index:
        name = 'tags'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }

    class Django:
        model = Tag
        fields = [
            'name',
            'description',
            # 'color_code',
            # 'has_followed',
        ]


@registry.register_document
class CommentDocument(Document):

    """Comment Document"""

    owner = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'email': fields.TextField(),
        'username': fields.TextField(),
        'auth_provider': fields.TextField(),
        'account_types': fields.TextField(),
        'profile': fields.TextField(),
        'uuid': fields.TextField(),
        'status': fields.TextField(),
    })

    post = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
    })

    class Index:
        name = 'comments'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }

    class Django:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'id',
            'body',
            # 'created',
            # 'modified',
        ]


@registry.register_document
class GradeLevel(Document):

    """Grade Level Document."""

    class Index:
        name = 'grades'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }

    class Django:
        model = ClassGrade
        fields = [
            'id',
            'grade',
            # 'country',
            # 'color_code',
        ]


@registry.register_document
class BlogDocument(Document):

    """BlogDocument"""

    owner = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'email': fields.TextField(),
        'username': fields.TextField(),
        'auth_provider': fields.TextField(),
        'account_types': fields.TextField(),
        'profile': fields.TextField(),
        'uuid': fields.TextField(),
        'status': fields.TextField(),
    })

    tags = fields.ObjectField(
        properties={
            'id': fields.IntegerField(),
            'email': fields.TextField(),
            'username': fields.TextField(),
            'auth_provider': fields.TextField(),
            'account_types': fields.TextField(),
            'profile': fields.TextField(),
            'uuid': fields.TextField(),
            'status': fields.TextField(),
        })

    comments = fields.ObjectField(
        properties={
            'id': fields.IntegerField(),
            'body': fields.TextField(),
            'owner': fields.TextField(),
            'post': fields.TextField(),
            'created': fields.TextField(),
            'modified': fields.TextField(),
        })

    grade_level = fields.ObjectField(
        properties={
            'id': fields.IntegerField(),
            'grade': fields.TextField(),
            'country': fields.TextField(),
            'color_code': fields.TextField(),
        }
    )

    class Index:
        name = 'blogs'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }

    # TODO: Add pending fields in each class :(
    class Django:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'body',
            'image',
            'status',
            # 'modified',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem like in [SerializationError Rebuilding Elastic Search Django App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861283/serializationerror-rebuilding-elastic-search-django-app) asked question.

The problem happens because your 'account_types' is ManyToMany field and when returning it gives back a queryset which can not be serialized by elasticsearch.

Before returning account_types put it in list() or you can use list comprehension.